# string and 4-byte Unicode characters

Tags: c#, string, unicode, astral-plane

I have one question about strings and chars in C#. I found that a string in C# is a Unicode string, and a char takes 2 bytes. So every char is in UTF-16 encoding. That's great, but I also read on Wikipedia that there are some characters that in UTF-16 take 4 bytes.

I'm doing a program that lets you draw characters for alphanumerical displays. In program there is also a tester, where you can write some string, and it draws it for you to see how it looks.

So how I should work with strings, where the user writes a character which takes 4 bytes, i.e. 2 chars. Because I need to go char by char through the string, find this char in the list, and draw it into the panel.

Comment: Going char by char simply doesn't work. Even going codepoint by codepoint doesn't work, because there are combining characters, ligatures, control characters, etc.

Comment: Correct display representation units are called `grapheme clusters`. Sometimes they are more than one code point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You you could do:

```
for( int i = 0; i < str.Length; ++i ) {
    int codePoint = Char.ConvertToUTF32( str, i );
    if( codePoint > 0xffff ) {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Then the `codePoint` represents any possible code point as a 32 bit integer.

Comment: This looks pretty simple and clear how it works. Thank you
But now I tried to find some 4 bytes UTF-16 character, and I wasn't succesful, or this character is represented as '' so this is almost absolutely pointless question. But thanks

Comment: Here's a character which definitely takes 2 chars: 

Comment: Did some playing around, if you make a string `""`, it'll report its `Length` as `2`.

If you do `Char.ConvertToUTF32("", 0)` you get `73760` (exceeds `char.MaxValue`)

But if you do `Char.ConvertToUTF32("", 1)` you get an error: `Found a low surrogate char without a preceding high surrogate at index: 1`.

In other words, according to the spec it knows that this is the tail end of a 2-char character, and so it's invalid to pass only the second char of the pair. Also no overloads of that method take a single char, either a string with an index or else a pair of chars.

Answer (score 1):

Work entirely with `String` objects; don't use `Char` at all. Example using [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx):

```
var needle = "ℬ";    // U+1D49D (I think)
var hayStack = "a code point outside basic multi lingual plane: ℬ";
var index = heyStack.IndexOf(needle);
```

Most methods on the `String` class have overloads which accept `Char` or `String`. Most methods on `Char` have overrides which use `String` as well. Just don't use `Char`.

Comment: I'm going to profess ignorance about combining characters, control characters, etc. I don't know enough about them to handle them correctly. Read up about Unicode in .NET and write some tests!